# How to insert a column from dataframe A into dataframe B which has a different lenght?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 dataframes:

a) df_Q, has the name of a district and its longitude and latitude. The names of the districts repeat accoding to the number of coordinates.

b) df_S, has the name (featureId) of a district and a count of its events. Here, the names of the districts repeat only once.

I need to insert the column "count" (from df_S) into df_Q. How can I make a sort of "mapping" so that this "count" repeats for each district (See **new_df_Q**)

This is my attempt:

```
df_Q['count']=df_Q.groupby('name').name.transform(lambda x: df_S['count'])
```

And this is the error:

```
ValueError: Length of passed values is 638, index implies 18
```

**df_Q**

[[image: df_S]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQwFL.png)

**df_S**

[image]

**new_df_Q**  --->  THIS IS WHAT I NEED

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "merge" function like this :

```
new_df_Q = df_Q.merge(df_S, how = 'left', left_on = 'name', right_on = 'featureId')
```

Comment: there is a problem whenever df_S has no values in the column "featureId". Is there a way to tell that whenever values are missing, to add '0'

Comment: You can handle this by applying the "fillna" function on the 'count' column :
**new_df_Q.count = new_df_Q.count.fillna(0)** just after **new_df_Q = df_Q.merge(df_S, how = 'left', left_on = 'name', right_on = 'featureId')**